# Filter Pandas DataFrame using a while loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to access filtered versions of a dataframe, using a list with the filter values.

I'm using a while loop that I thought would plug the appropriate list values into a dataframe filter one by one. This code prints the first one fine but then prints 4 empty dataframes afterwards.

I'm sure this is a quick fix but I haven't been able to find it.

```
boatID = [342, 343, 344, 345, 346]
i = 0 
while i < len(boatID):
    df = df[(df['boat_id']==boatID[i])]
    #run some code, i'm printing DF.head to test it works
    print(df.head())
    i = i + 1
```

Example dataframe:

```
   boat_id  activity speed  heading
0      342         1  3.34   270.00
1      343         1  0.02     0.00
2      344         1  0.01   270.00
3      345         1  8.41   293.36
4      346         1  0.03    90.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'm not trying to return a bool value generated by `isin`, I'm trying to filter the DF where `boat_id` == some number.

Comment: Update, using `int(boatID[i])` doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you overwrite `df` by `df` in `df = df[(df['boat_id']==boatID[i])]`:

Maybe you need change output to new dataframe, e.g. `df1`:

```
boatID = [342, 343, 344, 345, 346]
i = 0 
while i < len(boatID):
    df1 = df[(df['boat_id']==boatID[i])]
    #run some code, i'm printing DF.head to test it works
    print(df1.head())
    i = i + 1

#   boat_id  activity  speed  heading
#0      342         1   3.34      270
#   boat_id  activity  speed  heading
#1      343         1   0.02        0
#   boat_id  activity  speed  heading
#2      344         1   0.01      270
#   boat_id  activity  speed  heading
#3      345         1   8.41   293.36
#   boat_id  activity  speed  heading
#4      346         1   0.03       90
```

If you need filter dataframe `df` with column `boat_id`  by list `boatID` use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1 = df[(df['boat_id'].isin(boatID))]
print df1
#   boat_id  activity  speed  heading
#0      342         1   3.34   270.00
#1      343         1   0.02     0.00
#2      344         1   0.01   270.00
#3      345         1   8.41   293.36
#4      346         1   0.03    90.00
```

EDIT:

I think you can use [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python) of `dataframes`:

```
print df
   boat_id  activity  speed  heading
0      342         1   3.34   270.00
1      343         1   0.02     0.00
2      344         1   0.01   270.00
3      345         1   8.41   293.36
4      346         1   0.03    90.00

boatID = [342, 343, 344, 345, 346]

dfs = ['df' + str(x) for x in boatID]
dicdf = dict()

print dfs
['df342', 'df343', 'df344', 'df345', 'df346']

i = 0 
while i < len(boatID):
    print dfs[i]
    dicdf[dfs[i]] = df[(df['boat_id']==boatID[i])]
    #run some code, i'm printing DF.head to test it works
#    print(df1.head())
    i = i + 1
```

```
print dicdf
{'df344':    boat_id  activity  speed  heading
2      344         1   0.01      270, 'df345':    boat_id  activity  speed  heading
3      345         1   8.41   293.36, 'df346':    boat_id  activity  speed  heading
4      346         1   0.03       90, 'df342':    boat_id  activity  speed  heading
0      342         1   3.34      270, 'df343':    boat_id  activity  speed  heading
1      343         1   0.02        0}

print dicdf['df342']
   boat_id  activity  speed  heading
0      342         1   3.34      270
```

Comment: thanks, this looks like it concatenates all the DF's into 5 dtype objects, in one DF, is that correct?

Comment: Now it creates 5 new dataframes `df1` from `df`. In next loop old `df1` is overwritten new `df1`

Comment: Is it possible rather than have df1 overwritten each time the loop runs, have something like `df[i]` to create 5 dataframes with a unique name like df342, df343 etc?